# remove punctuation but keeping hashtag

Tags: r

can I remove punctuation using gsub but keeping hashtag "#" not being removed?

```
Data_edited_txt <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", Data_edited_txt)

structure(list(text = structure(c(4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("#AirAsia @AirAsiaId finally they let us fly with 9.20 flight today. Manual boarding pass. Phew, that was a #great relief!", 
"@AirAsia your direct debit (Maybank) payment gateways is not working. Is it something you are working to fix?", 
"RT @AirAsia: Kindly note that CIMB Direct Debit service will be unavailable tonight from (GMT+8) 1145hrs on 31 Jan until 0600hrs on 3 Feb 2â€¦", 
"RT @AirAsia: Skipped breakfast this morning? Now you can enjoy a #great breakfast onboard with our new breakfast meals! http://t.co/957ZaLjYâ€¦", 
"xdek ke flight @AirAsia Malaysia to LA... hahah..bagi la promo murah2 sikit, kompom aku beli...", 
"You know there is a problem when customer service asks you to wait for 103 minutes and your no is 42 in the queue. #AirAsia"
), class = "factor"), created = structure(c(5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("1/2/2014 16:14", "1/2/2014 17:00", "3/2/2014 0:54", 
"3/2/2014 0:58", "3/2/2014 1:28"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("text", 
"created"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: something like `gsub("[!@#$%^&*()-_=+'|?/]","",Data_edited_txt)` ?

Comment: Or `gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]#]", "", Data_edited_txt$text)`

Comment: You could also find the substring index for each hashtag, replace all punctuation with a space, then insert a hashtag into each substring index. Probably overkill though.